# System status blank - error message changing resource url

Tags: system-status

I'm trying to set up two civicrm installs.  both on same host but  with different domains.

First install seems to be fine so far.

Second install has blank system status page.

I have previously fixed this by changing resource urls to absolute paths so I thought to try this (although I don't know why this should be required as the other install is fine!)

but trying to change the resource urls gives this error:

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enabled in your browser settings. Please check this setting and enable cookies (if they are not enabled). Then try again. If this error persists, contact the site administrator for assistance.
Site Administrators: This error may indicate that users are accessing this page using a domain or URL other than the configured Base URL. EXAMPLE: Base URL is http://example.org, but some users are accessing the page via http://www.example.org or a domain alias like http://myotherexample.org.
Error type: Could not find a valid session key.

What is wrong with this installation?

Comment: update: the only difference I could find between the environments for the two installs was the php.ini file so i have now ensured both are using the same php.ini  which has changed the problem but not fixed it.  interestingly the system status page is now even more blank in that even the warning message has disapperead it now reads just "Powered by CiviCRM 5.4.0. CiviCRM is openly available under the GNU AGPL License." ie the  System Status: Warning or System Status Error part of the message has disappeared.  I can change resource ulrs now to but doing so doesnt fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The system status page uses ajax requests. Browsers won't let ajax requests access data on a server that has a different hostname from the one where the request started.

So your second install can be accessed by a different domain but thinks it has another name. You can check this in your browser's developer tools -> network tab to see what url the system status page is trying to access.

For example you are visiting my2ndsite.org but the system status page is trying to access someOtherName.org.

If you state which http server (e.g. apache) and which CMS (e.g. drupal) and maybe some details about your virtual host config it would help give a more specific answer.

Comment: Its a Wordpress install on an Apache server.  the urls that the systemstatus page is trying to access look correct on the respective installs....